# Removing anything after number in string

Tags: java, string

How to remove characters after  number in android

suppose my strings are

```
A1SS
A2SS
2SS
3SS
5SS
```

My Output Should be

```
A1
A2
2
3
5
```

Comment: I guess you mean In Java not in Android !

Comment: Ya its java in android

Comment: @DineshReddy please look my [code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42407230/5962715)

Comment: May there be more than one digit? May there be no digit at all, and if so, what should be the result?

Comment: @DineshReddy check my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42407230/5962715) I did it for all your cases

Comment: @CoDFather, I think the asker should be able to find your answer even if you don’t spam with comments. Also please be patient; sometimes an asker only gets back to Stack Overflow after some hours, a day or even longer. Thanks.

Comment: I think @DineshReddy didn't explain all cases of his problem.
maybe there is more than one number in a string so what the expected result for the problem the string with last number or with just first number.

Answer (score 1):

Use `for` to do it.

**UPDATE** case `AA22S` to `AA22`. Thanks @meo_3_the.

For example:

```
    String s = "A1SS";
    StringBuilder newStr = new StringBuilder("");
    boolean detected = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (s.charAt(i) >= '0' && s.charAt(i) <= '9'){
            newStr.append(s.charAt(i));
            detected = true;
        }else{
            if (!detected)
                newStr.append(s.charAt(i));
            else
                break;
        }
    }
```

Result String: `newStr.toString();`

Answer (score 1):

i think this might help you.

```
String value = your_string.replaceAll("[^0-9]","");
```

Answer (score 1):

simple way :

```
         String input="mhd60oug",result;
         int LastDigitid = -1;
       for(int i=0; i < input.length(); i++){
           char c = input.charAt(i);
           if(Character.isDigit(c)){
               LastDigitid = i;
           }
       }
       if(LastDigitid != -1){
          result = input.substring(0,LastDigitid+1);
       }
       else{
           result = input;
       }
       System.out.println(result);
```

**update** :

this way will only work after the last number in a String.the asker didn't explain exactly which case he wants in his problem.

there are several main cases :

> 1. `String` with more than one number like `A1SS23BD`:

in this case which exactly the result you want `A1` or `A1SS23`?

2. `String` with only one number like `2SS`
3. `String` that doesn't contain any number like `ASS`
4. `String` with only a number like `23`

Comment: The main method is Character.isDigit(char) which does the job!

Answer (score 0):

let us suppose you are getting the value in a variable called **output**.

To remove one **SS** in a String, you can use replace

```
output = output.replace("SS", "");
```

Or if you have to remove more than one **SS** in a String, you can use replaceAll

```
output = output.replaceAll("SS", "");
```

Comment: why down vote ? As per the question, its a valid answer.

Comment: Yeah. Sorry for downvoting. I realized that this is a valid answer. Anyway, it   only help small range case, not all cases.

Comment: as per the question, he has a small range case and not mentioned all cases. So i tried to stick to the question. No problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple way**:   More faster than other ways

```
public String getData(String val){
        String dat =val;
        boolean intFound=false;
        for (int i=0; i < val.length(); i++) {
            char c = val.charAt(i);
            if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
                dat = val.substring(0, i + 1);
                intFound = true;
            } else if (intFound) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return dat;
    }
```

Use above method and

```
String data=getData("A1SS");
```

**Simplicity**

it will work your all cases

- `"A434AS"` RETURNS `"A434"`.
- `"3FG"` RETURNS `"3"`.
- `"ERT45"` RETURNS `"ERT45"`.
- `"SDF34DFG2"` RETURNS `"SDF34"`     THANKS TO  Ole V.V

> **Logic:**
>
> 1. passing string to method.
> 2. Detecting integer position in `String`
> 3. Ignoring another charecter which comes after integer
> 4. returning `substring` to that position

Thanks to Mr. Rabbit

Comment: 1st place is not a number, so you return the whole String. Wrong answer.

Comment: @TruongHieu NOW ITS PERFECTLY CORRECT

Comment: @TruongHieu first time I just typed

Comment: Should there be more than one number, you seem to cut off only after the last one. `Q2E5U` gives `Q2E5`. It may not be relevant.

Comment: @OleV.V. thanks for the suggestion. Now I passed that

Answer (score 0):

You can use below method, that will work in all the cases.

```
    public String getModifiedString(String string) {
        String modifiedString = "";

        for(int index = 0; index < string.length(); index++) {
            char currentChar = string.charAt(index);
            if(Character.isLetter(currentChar)) {
                modifiedString += currentChar;
            } else if(Character.isDigit(currentChar)) {
                modifiedString += currentChar;

                for(int digitIndex = index+1; digitIndex < string.length(); digitIndex++) {
                    if(Character.isDigit(string.charAt(digitIndex))) {
                        modifiedString += string.charAt(digitIndex);
                    }
                }

                return modifiedString;
            }
        }

        return modifiedString;
    }
```

You can try it by just pasting below it in your code.

```
String[] stringArray = new String[]{"A1SS", "A2SS", "2SS", "AA222SS", "AN33"};
Log.d("---SO", " str 1: " + getModifiedString(stringArray[0]));
Log.d("---SO", " str 2: " + getModifiedString(stringArray[1]));
Log.d("---SO", " str 3: " + getModifiedString(stringArray[2]));
Log.d("---SO", " str 4: " + getModifiedString(stringArray[3]));
Log.d("---SO", " str 5: " + getModifiedString(stringArray[4]));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it’s simplest to use a regular expression (regex or regexp among friends):

```
private static final Pattern PAT_UNTIL_NUMBER = Pattern.compile("^[^0-9]*[0-9]+");

public static String removeCharsAfterNumber(String stringWithNumber) {
    Matcher m = PAT_UNTIL_NUMBER.matcher(stringWithNumber);
    if (m.find()) {
        return m.group();
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No number in string " + stringWithNumber);
        // or depending on requirements, may just return stringWithNumber
    }
}
```

Given the strings in your question, this method produces the output you asked for. It takes into account that your number may consist of more than one digit. For example, `A27B` becomes `A27`. It truncates after the first number if there are more than one, for example, `A7B4SS` gives `A7`. If you want different behaviour, it’s probably not difficult to modify the regular expression to your requirements.

I will not explain the basics of regexps here. There are some tutorials out there, use your search engine. You will of course want to understand what is happening in the code.

If for one reason or another you cannot or do not want to use a regexp, some of the other answers demonstrate how to hand program a solution. Here’s my version for good measure. I hope the comments explain what is going on, and I myself consider it simple and straightforward.

```
    int index = 0;
    // find the number
    while (index < stringWithNumber.length() && ! Character.isDigit(stringWithNumber.charAt(index))) {
        index++;
    }
    if (index == stringWithNumber.length()) { // no number found
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No number in string " + stringWithNumber);
    }
    // find end of number
    while (index < stringWithNumber.length() && Character.isDigit(stringWithNumber.charAt(index))) {
        index++;
    }
    return stringWithNumber.substring(0, index);
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You can use regex to achieve your need or iterate on the String to compute the end index on which you could perform a substring.

2) In your examples you don't show cases whereyou truncate the String after a series of digit.
 I will show you both solutions

3) With iteration over the String, the general idea is : either the searched pattern was not detected, so you return the original string, either it it was detected, you return the substring associated to.

Here is a class that provides one method for each case and with a sample ex :

```
public class TruncateStringAfterDigit {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s = "ba123";

        String valueTrimedAfterDigits = getValueTrimedAfterDigits(s);
        System.out.println(valueTrimedAfterDigits);

        String valueTrimedAfterDigit = getValueTrimedAfterOneDigit(s);
        System.out.println(valueTrimedAfterDigit);
    }

    private static String getValueTrimedAfterDigits(String s) {

        boolean isAtLeastANumberFound = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {

            if (Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))) {
                isAtLeastANumberFound = true;
            }

            else if (isAtLeastANumberFound) {
                return s.substring(0, i+1);
            }
        }

        return s;
    }

    private static String getValueTrimedAfterOneDigit(String s) {

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {

            if (Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))) {
                return s.substring(0, i + 1);
            }
        }

        return s;
    }
}
```

The rendered output :

> ba123
>
> ba1

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
output = output.replaceAll("[^\\d]*$", "");
```

**[^\d]*$** - this regex deletes all symbols after the last number

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/k20Lsd/1)

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score -1):

If the input is AB22CD, you want the result is AB22 or just AB2.
Edit: so maybe you can use this code:

```
public String removeCharactersAfterNumber(String input) {
    int index;
    for (index = 0; index < input.length(); index++) {
        if (input.charAt(index)  >= '0' && input.charAt(index) <= '9'){
            break;
        }
    }
    while (input.charAt(index)  >= '0' && input.charAt(index) <= '9') index++;
    return input.substring(0, index);
}
```

Comment: i Want the result as AB22

Comment: if you have comments, there is a comment section under the question !

Comment: Comment cái ăn phốt luôn :v

Comment: @AtefHares not enough reputation for comment, sir